# Is there any way to have some operation on a video file (.mkv) on client side using javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to do some operations on a video file in client side.
when user opens a video file (.mkv) in his browser I want to at first convert the file to an audio file such as mp3. then split that file into 4 or more files.
I mean for example if there is a video file that is 10 minutes; i want to get 5 mp3 files that each one of them is 2 minutes.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to do this in the client side for many valid reasons. The best way would be to upload the file to the server. then, use a library like https://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx to convert the file to your desired format and send it back to the client for download.

Comment: Yes, thank you for helping.
But the problem is exactly right there, I don't want to upload the file to the server.
because mostly the size of videos are big and this way has lack of performance for users.

Comment: This is one of the main reasons you don't wont to handle it in the client side. The file is huge, so even if you convert it to a binary or Blob and write a bunch of code to somehow convert it to another format it will block your main thread and will cause the browser to crash. you can probably take it out to a web worker but even then, writing this code is a huge pain and I won't recommend it at all.